# How could i document java.util.Map using spring docs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

Imagine I have  next class

```
public class MyDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;
    private Map<String, String> names;

    // public Getters and Setters
}
```

When I use the next code to document it with Spring

```
private static FieldDescriptor[] myDTOFields() {
  return new FieldDescriptor[] { 
    fieldWithPath("id").description("id description"),
    fieldWithPath("names").description("Names description") };
}
```

It doesn't work and I get an error.

> org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: The following
>   parts of the payload were not documented:
>
> ```
> {
>   "names" : {
>     "en" : "test"
>   }
> }
> ```

So how could I document java.util.Map with spring docs?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-request-response-payloads-fields), you could use `PayloadDocumentation.subsectionWithPath(“names”)` for this. It will mean that REST Docs considers `names` and everything that it contains as having been documented.